# Change all `=` to `eq` for emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, emacs24, emacs-prelude

Recently, I often encounter errors like this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument number-or-marker-p nil)
```

I found that in some situations, the error is caused by expressions like this:

```
(= nil 4)
```

I'm not sure whether this expression is intended to write like this, but it will work only if I change it to:

```
(eq nil 4)
```

However, (1) I need to replace all `=` to `eq` in that emacs lisp script (2) I'm not sure the codes should be modified like this.

I was wondering that whether I can write a few lines in the config file (`.emacs`) instead of modify on the source code to get things done. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't do this.

You're going down the path of hiding errors in code.  Figure out the root
cause of why you're passing nil to `=` and fix that.

Comment: Yes. @Firegun I saw you questions, you should figure out what exactly is going on.

Comment: In other words, the bug is that the variable you are comparing to 4 should not be `nil` and you fix the bug by guarding against this earlier in the code, probably by reporting an error when the variable gets assigned, probably by a function which is assumed to return a value but which doesn't.